# Replace string of characters (name+surname to email) Regex

Tags: regex, replace

I have a very big .doc file that has lots of clients info and I need to find/replace with the following logic:

```
Surname1 Surname2, Name -> Name.Surname1.Surname2@xxxxxx.com
```

I was trying to mess with notepad++ but I don't really have the knowledge needed with regex.

**From comments**

```
Jordan Parks
Kevin Johanson Larsson
Oleg Garcia Cruz
Jose Rondo Curry
Tim Bush Gallagher
Victoria
```

Comment: Would you mind some more info? thanks!

Comment: Yep, but how can I open the .doc file with thousands of records with that arrangement on excel?

Comment: No, it's not :(

Comment: post some portion of the data.

Comment: Jordan Parks, Kevin
Johanson Larsson, Oleg
Garcia Cruz, Jose
Rondo Curry, Tim
Bush Gallagher, Victoria

(one line each)

Comment: You can do it using notepad++, make sure it is in regex mode. 1. find `(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)` replace with ` \3\.\1\.\2 `     2. find ` (\w+\.\w+\.\w+) ` replace with ` \1\.@xxxxxx.com `

Comment: Pease explain: how do you have the data? JSON, DB, HTML, XML, simple .txt . . .This is important,

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+)\h*(\S+)?\h*(\S+)?$`
- Replace with: `(?3$3.$1.$2:(?2$2.$1:$1))@xx.com`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  (\S+)     : group 1, 1 or more non space character
  \h*       : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  (\S+)?    : optional group 2, 1 or more non space character
  \h*       : 0 or more horizontal spaces
  (\S+)?    : optional group 3, 1 or more non space character
$           : end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?3         : if group 3 exists
  $3.$1.$2  : concatenate group 3 (name) then group 1 (surname1) then group 2 (surname2)
  :         : else (group 3 does not exist)
  (?2       : if group 2 exists
    $2.$1   : concatenate group 2 (name) then group 1 (surname1)
    :       : else, group 2 does not exist
    $1      : group 1 (name)
  )
)
@xx.com     : literally
```

**Given:**

```
Jordan Parks
Kevin Johanson Larsson
Oleg Garcia Cruz
Jose Rondo Curry
Tim Bush Gallagher
Victoria
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Parks.Jordan@xx.com
Larsson.Kevin.Johanson@xx.com
Cruz.Oleg.Garcia@xx.com
Curry.Jose.Rondo@xx.com
Gallagher.Tim.Bush@xx.com
Victoria@xx.com
```